# How to dynamically set default firewall rules for a VPC network created using the google-terraform-network?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-modules

I want to create a VPC network using the `google-terraform-network` module. Additionally, I want to assign either user-defined or the default firewall rules to the `firewall_rules` parameter of the module.
The tricky part is that the default rules shall restrict the source ranges to the local IP, which is resolved dynamically. Thus, I can't provide the default value in the `variables.tf` file, i.e.: The following **won't** work:

```
variable "rules" {
    description = "List of rule definitions"
    default     = [
        {
        name                    = "allow-ssh-ingress"
        direction               = "INGRESS"
        ranges                  = [format("%s/%s", data.external.my_ip_addr.result["internet_ip"], 32)]
// ...
```

because `Error: Function calls not allowed`

I tried the following workarounds but none of them works.

#### Approach 1

Set `default=null`, and then use the `try` function.

```
variable "rules" {
    description = "List of rule definitions"
    default =    null
```

```
    firewall_rules = try(var.rules, [{
      name                    = "allow-ssh-ingress"
      direction               = "INGRESS"
      ranges                  = [format("%s/%s", data.external.my_ip_addr.result["internet_ip"], 32)]
      allow = [{
        protocol = "tcp"
        ports    = ["22"]
      }]
      deny = []
    }])
```

Error:  `A null value cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.`.
It seems that the `try` function ignores the fact that `var.rules` is `null`. It takes it as it is and tries to evaluate the expression using `null`.

#### Approach 2

Variable `rules` is still `null`, but this time I tried the ternary operator:

```
    firewall_rules = var.rules != null ? var.rules : [{
      name                    = "allow-ssh-ingress"
      direction               = "INGRESS"
      ranges                  = [format("%s/%s", data.external.my_ip_addr.result["internet_ip"], 32)]
      allow = [{
        protocol = "tcp"
        ports    = ["22"]
      }]
      deny = []
    }]
```

Error: `The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The 'true' value is list of object, but the 'false' value is tuple.` 
I don't know why, but it interprets the provided object as a tuple.

#### Approach 3

Explicitly cast the provided object to a list:

```
    firewall_rules = var.rules != null ? var.rules : tolist([{
      name                    = "allow-ssh-ingress"
      direction               = "INGRESS"
      ranges                  = [format("%s/%s", data.external.my_ip_addr.result["internet_ip"], 32)]
      allow = [{
        protocol = "tcp"
        ports    = ["22"]
      }]
      deny = []
    }])
```

But now it says:  `The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. Mismatched list element types: Type mismatch for object attribute "allow": The 'true' value is list of object, but the 'false' value is tuple.`

---

What's the correct way to provide the default input with a dynamic element when there is no input from the user?

Here's the complete definition of the `rules` variable:

```
variable "rules" {
    description = "List of rule definitions"
    default =    null
    type = list(object({
        name                    = string
        description             = optional(string)
        direction               = optional(string)
        priority                = optional(number)
        ranges                  = optional(list(string))
        source_tags             = optional(list(string))
        source_service_accounts = optional(list(string))
        target_tags             = optional(list(string))
        target_service_accounts = optional(list(string))
        allow = optional(list(object({
            protocol = string
            ports    = optional(list(string))
        })))
        deny = optional(list(object({
            protocol = string
            ports    = optional(list(string))
        })))
        log_config = optional(object({
            metadata = string
        }))
    }))
}
```

And the relevant part of the `main.tf`:

```
module "vpc" {
    source  = "terraform-google-modules/network/google"
    version = "~> 7.0"

    project_id   = var.project
    network_name = var.network_name
    routing_mode = "GLOBAL"

    subnets = [
        {
            subnet_name   = var.subnet_name
            subnet_ip     = var.subnet_ip
            subnet_region = var.region
        },
    ]

    firewall_rules = var.rules != null ? var.rules : tolist([{
      name                    = "allow-ssh-ingress"
      direction               = "INGRESS"
      ranges                  = [format("%s/%s", data.external.my_ip_addr.result["internet_ip"], 32)]
      allow = tolist([{
        protocol = "tcp"
        ports    = ["22"]
      }])
      deny = []
    }])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your rules as `type = list(any)`, or you have to **explicitly** provide `null` values for every single optional argument that you have in rule's type:

```
    firewall_rules = var.rules != null ? var.rules : tolist([{
      name                    = "allow-ssh-ingress"
      direction               = "INGRESS"
      ranges                  = [format("%s/%s", data.external.my_ip_addr.result["internet_ip"], 32)]
      description             = tostring(null)
      priority                = tonumber(null)
      source_tags             = tolist([tostring(null)])
      source_service_accounts = tolist([tostring(null)])
      target_tags             = tolist([tostring(null)])
      target_service_accounts = tolist([tostring(null)])    
      allow = tolist([{
        protocol = "tcp"
        ports    = tolist(["22"])
      }])
     deny = tolist([{
            protocol = ""
            ports    = tolist([tostring(null)])
        }])
    log_config = {
            metadata = tostring(null)
        }   
    }])
```

Comment: If you set the type of the variable to `list(any)` and leave the expression as it is (first suggestion), you'll get the type mismatch again. On the other hand, when you explicitly provide null values for every optional argument (second suggestion), you will get a series of `Conflicting configuration arguments`.
I obtained the working configuration by setting the type to `list(any)` and providing only a set of attributes (as opposed to the original expression, none using any function) passed as an arg to the `tolist` function.

Comment: @RobertSzooba "Conflicting configuration arguments" - is some other issue related to your code. You will not get error with mismatch types in a true statement.